# Using C# to Call a PowerShell Script to Execute the Windows 'djoin' Command

Tags: c#, powershell

1. I have the following Windows batch command that works successfully from the Command Prompt: **djoin /provision /domain  /machineou  /machine  /savefile**
2. I have been able to wrap this Windows command in a PowerShell command:    
   **Invoke-Expression [djoin command]**
    and it works well when running it locally using PowerShell.
3. I am failing when I try to take the script in Step #2 and call it from a C# web application.  I'm trying the following:

   ```
   PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
   ps.addCommand("Invoke-Expression");
   ps.AddArgument("<djoin command>");
   ```

The web page doesn't give me any errors and I'm stuck on this.  Please let me know if you have any questions and thank you for your help.

Comment: are you familiar with the `Process  and ProcessInfo Classes` can you not to it that way along with ShellExecute cmd's ...?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the PowerShell engine to execute this, then do it this way:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) 
{
    ps.AddScript("djoin /provision /domain /machineou /machine /savefile");
    var results = ps.Invoke();
    foreach (var r in results) 
    {
        // do something with r
    }
}
```

Note: the use of Invoke-Expression is unnecessary. Also, as MethodMan suggests in his comment, you could just use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`.